# How to make a ranged for loop that iterates over elements in a list in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-3.0, django-3.1

I'm fairly new to Django 3, but I could not find any answer that shows the best way to use Django template syntax in order to iterate over the first five elements in a list given in the context.

For clarification, what I'm looking for is a way to do this:

(given the following list in the context`["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]`)
I want to display the first five elements in a way similar to this vanilla Python code:

```
for item in range(5):
    print(list[item])
```

I would even appreciate it if someone could try and show my how to break a loop in the templates (if it's even possible).
Is there a way to do any one of these?

Comment: `{% for item in list %} <p>{{ item }}</p> {% endfor %}`. And the pythonic way to iterate a `list` would be `for item in list:..print(item)`

Comment: I know about that, but the problem is that I need to *not* iterate over ALL the elements, but just the first five...

Comment: you can use the [forloop.counter0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) to check the current counter of iterations, i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
{% for item in list%}
    {% if forloop.counter < 6}
        // Do what you need
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{% with new_list=list|slice":5" %}
    {% for item in new_list %} 
        <h1>Check</h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

See: [django_template_with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) and [django_template_slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)